# Adding text label to a bar in fl_chart bar-chart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, fl-chart

I've built a Flutter app, and used `fl_chart` to present a bar chart.

It works great, but the only thing left it to add a label inside each bar, as in this UI design:

[image]

It seems `fl_chart` doesn't have a label property for the bar.

I've tried to add a simple `Text` widget on top of the chart using a `Stack`, but the calculation of the position of each label does not work on all screen sizes.

Does anyone know what is the best way to implement the label on the bar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think using a Stack could be the right approach.

Have you tried stacking another Chart on top of your barchart?

Maybe something like this:

```
           LineChart(
              LineChartData(
                ...
                titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                  bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                    showTitles: true,
                    getTextStyles: (double v) {
                      return TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0);
                    },
                    interval: [yourInterval],
                    getTitles: (value) {
                      ...
                    },
                  ),
                  leftTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                ),
                borderData: FlBorderData(
                  show: false,
                ),
                ...
              ),
            ),
```